# Javax mail with Lift framework

Tags: lift, jakarta-mail, javax.activation

I'm having a strange issue.

I deploy my webapp to the server (jetty 7.4.3.v20110701), and everything (including mailer) seem to be working fine. Debugging info (got with `-Djavax.activation.debug=true`) for sending an email looks like this:

```
MailcapCommandMap: createDataContentHandler for text/html
  search DB #0
    got content-handler
      class com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html
INFO  [qtp1699297250-32] net.liftweb.util.TimeHelpers.info[195] - Service request (GET) /reservation/276 returned 200, took 264 Milliseconds
INFO  [qtp1699297250-34] net.liftweb.util.TimeHelpers.info[195] - Service request (GET) /ajax_request/liftAjax.js returned 200, took 9 Milliseconds
MailcapCommandMap: createDataContentHandler for multipart/alternative
  search DB #0
    got content-handler
      class com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed
```

But then suddenly, out of nowhere the code just stops working:

```
Can't load DCH com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed; Exception: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/sun/mail/handlers/multipart_mixed
  search DB #1
  search DB #2
  search DB #3
  search fallback DB #0
  search fallback DB #1
    got content-handler
      class com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed
Can't load DCH com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed; Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/sun/mail/handlers/multipart_mixed
  search fallback DB #2
    got content-handler
      class com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed
Can't load DCH com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed; Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/sun/mail/handlers/multipart_mixed
  search fallback DB #3
ERROR [pool-3-thread-13] net.liftweb.util.MailerImpl.error[239] - Couldn't send mail
javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1141) ~[mail-1.4.4.jar:1.4.4]
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:189) ~[mail-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118) ~[mail-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at net.liftweb.util.MailerImpl$$anon$1$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(Mailer.scala:180) ~[lift-util_2.9.0-1-2.4-M1.jar:2.4-M1]
    at net.liftweb.util.MailerImpl$$anon$1$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(Mailer.scala:180) ~[lift-util_2.9.0-1-2.4-M1.jar:2.4-M1]
    at net.liftweb.util.MailerImpl$class.performTransportSend(Mailer.scala:174) ~[lift-util_2.9.0-1-2.4-M1.jar:2.4-M1]
    at net.liftweb.util.Mailer$.performTransportSend(Mailer.scala:31) ~[lift-util_2.9.0-1-2.4-M1.jar:2.4-M1]
    at net.liftweb.util.MailerImpl$class.msgSendImpl(Mailer.scala:276) ~[lift-util_2.9.0-1-2.4-M1.jar:2.4-M1]
    at net.liftweb.util.Mailer$.msgSendImpl(Mailer.scala:31) ~[lift-util_2.9.0-1-2.4-M1.jar:2.4-M1]
    at net.liftweb.util.MailerImpl$MsgSender$$anonfun$messageHandler$1.apply(Mailer.scala:158) [lift-util_2.9.0-1-2.4-M1.jar:2.4-M1]
    at net.liftweb.util.MailerImpl$MsgSender$$anonfun$messageHandler$1.apply(Mailer.scala:155) [lift-util_2.9.0-1-2.4-M1.jar:2.4-M1]
    at net.liftweb.actor.SpecializedLiftActor$class.execTranslate(LiftActor.scala:321) [lift-actor_2.9.0-1-2.4-M1.jar:2.4-M1]
    at net.liftweb.util.MailerImpl$MsgSender.execTranslate(Mailer.scala:154) [lift-util_2.9.0-1-2.4-M1.jar:2.4-M1]
    at net.liftweb.actor.SpecializedLiftActor$class.net$liftweb$actor$SpecializedLiftActor$$proc2(LiftActor.scala:289) [lift-actor_2.9.0-1-2.4-M1.jar:2.4-M1]
    at net.liftweb.actor.SpecializedLiftActor$$anonfun$net$liftweb$actor$SpecializedLiftActor$$processMailbox$1.apply(LiftActor.scala:210) [lift-actor_2.9.0-1-2.4-M1.jar:2.4-M1]
    at net.liftweb.actor.SpecializedLiftActor$$anonfun$net$liftweb$actor$SpecializedLiftActor$$processMailbox$1.apply(LiftActor.scala:210) [lift-actor_2.9.0-1-2.4-M1.jar:2.4-M1]
    at net.liftweb.actor.SpecializedLiftActor$class.around(LiftActor.scala:224) [lift-actor_2.9.0-1-2.4-M1.jar:2.4-M1]
        at net.liftweb.util.MailerImpl$MsgSender.around(Mailer.scala:154) [lift-util_2.9.0-1-2.4-M1.jar:2.4-M1]
    at net.liftweb.actor.SpecializedLiftActor$class.net$liftweb$actor$SpecializedLiftActor$$processMailbox(LiftActor.scala:209) [lift-actor_2.9.0-1-2.4-M1.jar:2.4-M1]
    at net.liftweb.actor.SpecializedLiftActor$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiftActor.scala:173) [lift-actor_2.9.0-1-2.4-M1.jar:2.4-M1]
    at net.liftweb.actor.LAScheduler$$anonfun$9$$anon$2$$anon$3.run(LiftActor.scala:64) [lift-actor_2.9.0-1-2.4-M1.jar:2.4-M1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [na:1.6.0_24]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [na:1.6.0_24]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_24]
Caused by: javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type multipart/alternative; 
    boundary="----=_Part_8_877795714.1310372068000"
    at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:877) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:302) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1403) ~[mail-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1745) ~[mail-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1099) ~[mail-1.4.4.jar:1.4.4]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

After some time it can start working again.

I've tried solutions, recommended [here](http://blog.hpxn.net/2009/12/02/tomcat-java-6-and-javamail-cant-load-dch/) and [here](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=237257). I've also tried excluding `javax.activation`, using both `javax.mail 1.4.1` and `1.4.4`. Neither solution worked. What could be the cause? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by making mail.jar and activation.jar `provided` in my pom.xml.

```
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
         <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
         <version>1.4.1</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
```

The reason, I suppose, was that container already had mail.jar, and jdk 1.6 includes activation.jar.